# How can I write a proper test with Mocha for a function with async await and try catch?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, async-await, mocha.js, try-catch

I have a function where I'm fetching all the authors from Mongodb. I'm new to testing, I spent hours myself and online trying to come up with good test cases but can't really figure how I can properly test the functionality here. errorHandler is just a class for error handling and wrap function just wraps the error with the description.

```
    const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
    const credentials = require('../database-credentials');
    const mongoClient = new MongoClient(credentials.URI,{useUnifiedTopology: true });
    mongoClient.connect();
    const mongodb = mongoClient.db();

    async getAllAuthors (cb) {
        try {
            const result = await mongodb.collection('authors').find({}).toArray();
            return cb(null, result);
        } catch (error) {
            return cb(errorHandler.wrap(error, 'while fetching all authors in the book'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a stub library like `sinon.js` to stub side effect method. For your case, the side effect method is `mongodb.collection().find().toArray()`. Each test case should test only one scenario.

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
const errorHandler = {
  wrap(error, message) {
    console.log(message);
    return error;
  },
};

export default class SomeClass {
  mongodb;
  constructor(mongodb) {
    this.mongodb = mongodb;
  }
  async getAllAuthors(cb) {
    try {
      const result = await this.mongodb
        .collection('authors')
        .find({})
        .toArray();
      return cb(null, result);
    } catch (error) {
      return cb(errorHandler.wrap(error, 'while fetching all authors in the book'));
    }
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import SomeClass from './';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('59609593', () => {
  let instance;
  const mongodbStub = {
    collection: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    find: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    toArray: sinon.stub(),
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    instance = new SomeClass(mongodbStub);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should find authors correctly', async () => {
    const callback = sinon.stub();
    mongodbStub.toArray.resolves([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);
    await instance.getAllAuthors(callback);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mongodbStub.collection, 'authors');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mongodbStub.find, {});
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mongodbStub.toArray);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(callback, null, [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);
  });

  it('should handle error', async () => {
    const callback = sinon.stub();
    const error = new Error('network error');
    mongodbStub.toArray.rejects(error);
    await instance.getAllAuthors(callback);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(callback, error);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  59609593
    ✓ should find authors correctly
while fetching all authors in the book
    ✓ should handle error


  2 passing (14ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.test.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

---

**Update**

If you use `require`/`import` statement to import your dependencies, E.g. the `mongodb` package. Here is the unit test solution:

`index-v2.js`:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const credentials = { URI: 'mongdb://127.0.0.1:27019' };
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(credentials.URI, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoClient.connect();
const mongodb = mongoClient.db();

const errorHandler = {
  wrap(error, message) {
    console.log(message);
    return error;
  },
};

class SomeClass {
  async getAllAuthors(cb) {
    try {
      const result = await mongodb
        .collection('authors')
        .find({})
        .toArray();
      return cb(null, result);
    } catch (error) {
      return cb(errorHandler.wrap(error, 'while fetching all authors in the book'));
    }
  }
}

module.exports = SomeClass;
```

`index-v2.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

describe('59609593', () => {
  const mongodbStub = {
    connect: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    db: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    collection: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    find: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    toArray: sinon.stub(),
  };
  let instance;
  before(() => {
    sinon.stub(mongodb, 'MongoClient').callsFake(() => mongodbStub);
    const SomeClass = require('./index-v2');
    instance = new SomeClass();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it('should  find authors', async () => {
    mongodbStub.toArray.resolves([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);
    const callback = sinon.stub();
    await instance.getAllAuthors(callback);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mongodbStub.collection, 'authors');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mongodbStub.find, {});
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mongodbStub.toArray);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(callback, null, [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);
  });

  it('should handle error', async () => {
    const callback = sinon.stub();
    const error = new Error('network error');
    mongodbStub.toArray.rejects(error);
    await instance.getAllAuthors(callback);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(callback, error);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  59609593
    ✓ should  find authors
while fetching all authors in the book
    ✓ should handle error


  2 passing (74ms)

------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File              |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index-v2.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index-v2.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mongoose5.x-lab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59609593

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! As a side note, I'm creating mongodb connection in SomeClass itself, so I can't really pass the mongodbstub to its constructor. Is there any other way for that you think? And is it a better practice overall to pass the database instance to functions who do database operations?

Comment: @someone Update your post, add the `mongodb` part code. Dependency Inject is a good practice for software development. One benefit is, It will make the code easier to test. But if you use `import` statement to import your dependencies, it's ok. It's testable.

Comment: Just updated @slideshowp2, I see, so it should still be testable like this?

Comment: @someone Updated answer, please check.